# C# - Pass hidden value from .NET Core View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass a hidden value from View to Controller in ASP.NET Core.

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostTest", "Test", FormMethod.Post)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id, new { @Value = "123456789" })
}
```

In my controller, I am receiving it as a model

```cs
public ActionResult TestId(ObjTest objTest)
{
     string result = objTest.id;
     Console.WriteLine(result) 
}
```

This is my model:

```cs
    public class ObjTest
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

However, I am unable to retrieve the value "123456789".

Comment: How do you call `TestId` action from `View`? Please share that code as well. If you are using `Form` & `Submit` button then make sure your `@Html.HiddenFor` line is written inside `Form`

Comment: @Karan Have edited my question! I  am using the `Html.BeginForm` for the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you modify the code like this?

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" value="123456789">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Use the `asp-for` attribute instead of `@Html.HiddenFor`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Html.Hidden`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("id", "123456789" )
  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

result:

[image]

If you want to use `@Html.HiddenFor`, you need to set the value in the get method, like below:

```
public ActionResult TestId()
        {
            var model = new ObjTest();
            model.id = "123456789";
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TestId(ObjTest objTest)
        {
            string result = objTest.id;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            return View();
        }
```

Then

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
```

Comment: @Jessica Please have a look at my answer.